# Dynamic update table rows using Postgres, without removing previous field

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

It may be a repeated question, but I'm not finding a good solution to my problem.

I simply have a row like this in Postgres:

```
 username         |   date   |       status        |        account_id        | last_update  | account_type |                     iban                     |                    email                     |                business_name                 
--------------------------+----------+---------------------+--------------------------+--------------+--------------+----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------
 tMCjBPQjE+9C     | 17-05-12 | CANCELLED           | axFOU38iBWRnfcAW11H7lg== | 16:42:17.962 | B            |                                              |
```

I hope you can see, that some column don't have the field.
Perfect so now, my problem is: 
If i want to update the row, and let's say the row I have doesn't have the account_id value BUT the status is different, so i need to update it. The result of the update will be updating the status field, and also the account_id, which will be empty. That is my problem. 
I don't want to update fields that are already filled with the information but only when they actually change. And that needs to be dynamyc because I don't know a priori which fields will be empty or not, but what I know is that IF the field is already enanched, then it's fine and must not be updated if the new row does not contain it.

So, for example, this row is the one that match the PK(USERNAME AND DATE) and has the status different from the one already stored in the table.

```
     username     |   date   |       status        |        account_id        | last_update  | account_type |                     iban                     |                    email                     |                business_name                 
    --------------------------+----------+---------------------+--------------------------+--------------+--------------+----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------
     tMCjBPQjE+9C | 17-05-12 | NEW                 |                          | 16:42:17.962 | B            |                                              |
```

as you can see, the row above has the different status, the key username and date match so i need to update! but in the update the field account_id must not be updated because I already have a value, is already enanched!

This must be valid for every element in the table, so let's say the next row has the `email, iban` field but not the `account_id`, I need to update the field that I don't have but do not touch the one that I already have.

The output, for the previous example, then it should be:

```
 username         |   date   |       status        |        account_id        | last_update  | account_type |                     iban                     |                    email                     |                business_name                 
--------------------------+----------+---------------------+--------------------------+--------------+--------------+----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------
 tMCjBPQjE+9C     | 17-05-12 | NEW                 | axFOU38iBWRnfcAW11H7lg== | 16:42:17.962 | B            |                                              |
```

Now, this is my statemen, it may be different than expected because I'm using Logstash output plugin in order to do the UPSERT function.

```
INSERT INTO users VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)
          on conflict (username,date)

          do update set (date,status, firstname, lastname, last_update) = (?,?,?,?,?)
          where users.username = ? "
          , "%{[request][username]}","%{date}","%{status}", "%{firstname}", "%{lastname}","%{time}","%{date}","%{status}", "%{firstname}", "%{lastname}","%{time}","%{[request][username]}"
```

each `?` is mapped in a way that the first `?` is `"%{[request][username]}"` the second is `"%{date}"` etc etc. This statement work, it does the update and the insert but when it comes to do the update as I described, is not doing the "dynamic" job I want.

Sorry if I didn't explain well, let me know if you need more clarification about the issue.

Comment: show your update statement?..

Comment: @VaoTsun I added my statement.

Comment: @VaoTsun any suggestion?

Comment: sorry - after hearing about Logstash plugin - no :)

Comment: Don't worry about the logstash plugin, I can handle it later....i hope :D I first need to understand how to do it in postgres, then will come logstash